# Is that possible to create multi-platform Swift Package with storyboards for different platforms?

Tags: ios, macos, swift-package

If I was creating a multi-platform code that includes storyboards for iOS and macOS, for example, I would mark each storyboard to its respective platform, the iOS storyboard to the iOS target and the Mac storyboard to the mac platform.

So I have zillions of files that are common to both platforms and these two storyboards, one for iOS and one for macOS.

How do I do that when I create a Swift Package?